# ios UiPickerView with CountryPicker class

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Im trying to add the UiPickerView class from https://github.com/nicklockwood/CountryPicker
I want to use with storyboard in my viewController but the delegate method is never getting called although the pickerView shows the countries. 
Here is what ive done:
ive imported the CountryPicker folder and Flags folder, in the storyboard controller ive added a UiPickerView and assign it to CountryPicker class.
The ViewController.h and .m files are exactly the same as the example.
i cant find what im missing.
Also i tried init the object and call the setSelectedCountry method from my ViewController.m file but its also not doing anything.
ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CountryPicker.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CountryPickerDelegate>

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 CountryPicker *picker = [[CountryPicker alloc] init];
 [picker.delegate self];
 [picker setSelectedCountryCode:@"US" animated:YES];
}

- (void)countryPicker:(__unused CountryPicker *)picker didSelectCountryWithName:(NSString *)name code:(NSString *)code
{
 NSLog(@"country: %@",name);
}


@end
```

Comment: Is a picker drawn on the storyboard already? The one you are allocating in `viewDidLoad` is not being added as a subView?

Comment: yes its already drawn on the storyboard with a custom class (CountryPicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an IBOutlet from the storyboard to your code [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-connections_bindings/CreatingOutlet.html)

Remove the code you have in your `viewDidLoad` that creates a new picker.

Then for the the new IBOutlet you've created, set `self` as the delegate, so if your outlet was called `picker` your `viewDidLoad` should look as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    [self.picker setSelectedCountryCode:@"US" animated:YES];
}
```